# How can I call an Encrypted Hive Box to a class?

Tags: flutter, encryption, hive, box

I am needing to encrypt a hive box, in which the box `'user_api'` is to be called in `Api_Page_()` to receive user input to store inside said box. However, the `encryptedBox` is not defined within the class. The Hive Docs display the encryption code is to be done inside of the `main()` function, which I have done, but I am unsure of how to take the box outside of `main()`.
Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

**My Code:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';



Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // HIVE ENCRYPTION----------------------------------------
  const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  final encryptionKey = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
  if (encryptionKey == null) {
    final key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
    await secureStorage.write(
      key: 'key',
      value: base64Encode(key),
    );
  }
  final key = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
  final encryptKey = base64Url.decode(key);
  print('Encryption key: $encryptKey');
  // HIVE ENCRYPTION----------------------------------------


  // HIVE INIT---------------------------------------------
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(directory.path);
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  final encryptedBox = Hive.openBox<String>('user_api', encryptionCipher: HiveAesCipher(encryptKey));     // Initially Opens Box on App Start
  // HIVE INIT---------------------------------------------



  runApp(myApp());
}


class myApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,    // Removes Debug Banner. [Delete before app release]
      title: 'App Title Placeholder',
      home: API_Page_()                   // Calls API_Page_ class from api_page.dart
    );
  }
}

class API_Page_ extends StatelessWidget {
  const API_Page_({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RaisedButton(onPressed: () { var eBox = encryptedBox<String>('user_api');
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```